# Syslog-NG two relay server issue

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

I am trying to forward logs through two syslog-ng relay server, which adds the first relay server IP as a source and in my SIEM, I am seeing all logs are coming from the first syslog relay server.

Setup is below.

Client --> Syslog-Relay1 ---> Syslog-Relay2 ---> SIEM

In SIEM I am seeing all the log source as Syslog-Relay1. I have played with multiple option, but no hope yet. Any idea what I am missing here ? I am not finding any proper documents / forums which explains this setup. This we are looking to meet some specific log flow, in case if you have a question why I am trying to achieve this. Thanks in advance

Following is my configuration:

Syslog-Relay1

```
@version:3.5
@include "scl.conf"

# syslog-ng configuration file.
#
# This should behave pretty much like the original syslog on RedHat. But
# it could be configured a lot smarter.
#
# See syslog-ng(8) and syslog-ng.conf(5) for more information.
#
# Note: it also sources additional configuration files (*.conf)
#       located in /etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/
options {
    time-reap(30);
    mark-freq(10);
#    keep-hostname(yes);
    keep-hostname(no);
    log_msg_size(65536);
    log_fifo_size(10000);
    threaded(yes);
    flush_lines(100);
    use_dns(no);
    stats_freq(60);
    mark_freq(36400);
    use_fqdn(no);
#    chain-hostnames(yes);
    chain-hostnames(no);
    };


source s_syslog_over_network {
        network(
                ip(0.0.0.0)
                log-fetch-limit(200)
                log-iw-size(1000000)
                keep-alive(yes)
                max_connections(10000)
                port(9999)
                transport("tcp")
                flags(no-parse)
        );
};


 destination d_syslog_tcp {
       network(
                "10.12.86.98"
                transport("tcp")
                port(12229)
        );
};

log {
        source(s_syslog_over_network);
        destination(d_syslog_tcp);
};
```

Syslog-Relay2

```
@version:3.5
@include "scl.conf"

# syslog-ng configuration file.
#
# This should behave pretty much like the original syslog on RedHat. But
# it could be configured a lot smarter.
#
# See syslog-ng(8) and syslog-ng.conf(5) for more information.
#
# Note: it also sources additional configuration files (*.conf)
#       located in /etc/syslog-ng/conf.d/
options {
    time-reap(30);
    mark-freq(10);
#    keep-hostname(yes);
    keep-hostname(no);
    log_msg_size(65536);
    log_fifo_size(10000);
    threaded(yes);
    flush_lines(100);
    use_dns(no);
    stats_freq(60);
    mark_freq(36400);
    use_fqdn(no);
#    chain-hostnames(yes);
    chain-hostnames(no);

    };


source s_syslog_over_network {
        network(
                ip(0.0.0.0)
                log-fetch-limit(200)
                log-iw-size(1000000)
                keep-alive(yes)
                max_connections(10000)
                port(12229)
                transport("tcp")
               flags(no-parse)
        );
};



destination d_syslog_tcp {
        network(
                "10.12.86.76"
                transport("tcp")
                port(12221)
        );
};

log {
        source(s_syslog_over_network);
        destination(d_syslog_tcp);
};
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried the tips described in https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/procedure-configuring-syslog-ng-relays.html and https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/example-how-relaying-works.html ?

Comment: yes. I indeed followed the guide and like I said, all issues are started when we introduce the second relay.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Client's IP address in SIEM, you have to:

1. set `keep-hostname(no)` and `use-dns(no)` on Syslog-Relay1

> This will discard the orginal `HOST` field of the messages of Client
>   and use the IP address of Client instead.

2. set `keep-hostname(yes)` on Syslog-Relay2

> On Syslog-Relay1, the HOST field of the message was overwritten. You
>   want to **keep** this and forward to SIEM.

3. remove `flags(no-parse)` from `s_syslog_over_network` on Syslog-Relay2

> The IP of Client is stored in the message, so it has to be parsed before forwarding towards SIEM.

Comment: @xor_lord If this corrected your problem, please mark it as the answer. If you don't know how, please view the help guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)